# Campaign object not available in Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, campaign, contactbuilder, data-synchronization

I am trying to synchronize the standard Campaign Object from Salescloud to Marketing Cloud but it doesn't appear in Data Sources / Set-Up Object. I am only having this issue with this object.

I checked the permissions and it seems okay. Have you ever encounter this issue?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000e9hVQAQ